# Pointer to struct with a two dimensional array

Tags: string, pointers, structure

i have this structure:

```
struct dict{
int len;
char (*dict0)[MAX_WORD_LEN+1];
char (*dict1)[MAX_WORD_LEN+1];
```

};

and i do this:

struct dict dictionary;
 struct dict *p_diction=&dictionary;
 but when i try to scanf with the pointer to pointer i get an error, naturally i is defined and everything.

scanf("%10s",p_diction->(*(dict0+i))[0]);

'expected identifier before '(' token

and no i dont want to scanf using &dictionary, as this also happens in other instances besides scanf.

what is the correct form to write the command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is

```
p_diction->dict0[i]
```

or

```
*(p_diction->dict0 + i)
```

You need to pass a pointer to `char` for the `%s` conversion, so the `char[MAX_WORD_LEN+1]` is okay (it will be converted to a pointer to the first `char` in it).

```
p_diction->dict0
```

gives you the pointer to the `char[MAX_WORD_LEN+1]`, and you want the `i`-th of these arrays, so you must increment this pointer by `i`. Then to get the right type of pointer, you must dereference to get the array. Then you can either use the automatic array-to-pointer conversion, or explicitly pass the address of the first `char` in the array

```
&p_diction->dict0[i][0]
```

With the two dereferencings you attempted, you would have passed a `char`, which would cause havoc. You need only one.